# Eloquent - Eager Loading Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to figure out how to eager load data from a related table. I have 2 models `Group` and `GroupTextPost`.

**Group.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Group extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'group';

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('\App\Models\GroupType');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User');
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\GroupTextPost');
    }
}
```

**GroupTextPost.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class GroupTextPost extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'group_text_post';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User');
    }

    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Group');
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is eager load the `user` when fetching group text posts so that when I pull the messages the user's name is included.

I've tried doing it like so:

```
public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\GroupTextPost')->with('user');
}
```

... and calling like so:

```
$group = Group::find($groupID);
$group->messages[0]->firstname
```

But I get an error:

```
Unhandled Exception: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::firstname()
```

Is this possible to do with Eloquent?

Comment: Try ```$m = $group->messages()->get();``` and then ```$m[0]->user[0]->first_name;```

Comment: Messages will have the first name or the user have?

Comment: @Dev user has the firstname.

Comment: Just dd($m), you will find array of messages having array of users inside. Iterate through each message and then user and you will get first name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should not eager load directly on the relationship. You could eager load the user always on the GroupTextPost model.

GroupTextPost.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class GroupTextPost extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'group_text_post';

    /**
     * The relations to eager load on every query.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $with = ['user'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User');
    }

    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Group');
    }
}
```

Or you could use [Nested Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```
$group = Group::with(['messages.user'])->find($groupID);
$group->messages[0]->user->firstname
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `$with` property. Where is this in the docs? That looks ideal.

Comment: I can't find in in the docs either. You can find it in the Model class. [See this line](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/3b7181e728d27a641e953ac22e93d91f87e46888/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L182)

Answer (score 1):

Create new relationship in `Message` model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\User');
}
```

Load both relations:

```
$group = Group::with('messages', 'messages.user')->find($groupID);

foreach ($group->messages as $message) {
    $message->user->firstname;
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: If it is a ```with``` clause and there is a hasMany relationship between messages and group then I think the returned message will have collection of user, not single object.

Answer (score 1):

You have to access the user before accessing directly the firstname.

`$group->messages[0]->user->firstname;`

The way you wrote it means the message has a firstname.